# How to fix ionic routes using href after build?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, build

I have an Angular/Ionic code which I want to build into the web app. I use `href` to connect different pages as is written in the Ionic docs.

When I use `ionic lab` for testing, everything works fine, but when I build the code, links don't work anymore, leaving me with 404 error.

I used this code for building:
`ionic build --prod`

One thing I can think of is that I did not add any `.htaccess` file. Am I supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

The href is worked in HTML prototyping, 
I think u have to use routerLink="./path" 
Try to check this : 
Angular routing :  https://angular.io/guide/router
Inoic routing : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router

Good luck